# Why was my flag of a rude post declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/94899/909) because it contains:

> The "chewing out" instructor is an idiot ...

> If this knucklehead is actually griping at students over this, ...

The flag was declined. In my opinion, this violates the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct):

> **No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.**
>
> Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

> **No name-calling or personal attacks.**
>
> Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).

In addition, it seems to me that the instructor being referenced, or others with the same ideas (described in the answer as "wrongheaded and foolish") may well end up here reading this answer. Because of the language used, such a person is likely to be offended and alienated. By toning down the language, wouldn't we be more likely to have a positive, constructive and persuasive influence? Isn't this the kind of community we want to be?

This question [made the Hot Network Questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?page=2) and has relatively high visibility.

With these points in mind, I'm confused - why was the flag declined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not flag that post. You flagged [your own answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/94894/1467).

In the mod interface, only your answer and its comments appeared.

I'll try to review the other answer.